# RuntimeError('dot : expected both vectors to have same dtype, but found Double and Float

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

I am trying to perform this operation:

```
L_c += 1 - torch.abs(torch.dot(nuNormalized, Nu))
```

where:

> nuNormalized -> tensor([ 0.3790, -0.4208,  0.8242], dtype=torch.float64)

> Nu -> tensor([-0.9961, -0.9961, -0.9961], device='cuda:0')

I am getting this error:

> (<class 'RuntimeError'>, RuntimeError('dot : expected both vectors to have same dtype, but found Double and Float',), <traceback object at 0x7f4d276155c8>)

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. The two objects you're trying to dot aren't of the same type. Just add `dtype=torch.float64` to the `Nu` instantiation just like you did for the normalized.

Comment: @blorgon Thanks for responding. I didnot actually do the assignments. The values of nuNormalized & Nu are result of some operations done previously. I have just mentioned the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast nuNormalized to float from double.

also you might consider moving both to the same device.